# Show/hide a series when hiding/showing another series

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I can't figure **this one*** out.

JS Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/elange/wcvsco0o/9/

Scenario: Showing the trend of Latte purchases over time against all other purchases.

This is always true: Latte + Other = All

Requirements:

1. The Latte count shows along the top of the total, as shown.
2. The user can see the trend of "Lattes" on its own, separate from "All purchases"

Current Solution: ghost the "other" purchases data to raise "Lattes" up to match the total of "All" while still showing the right amount of lattes in the tooltip. (Ideally, the tooltip and all elements for "Other" would be hidden.)

***Problem:** How do I take care of req. 2, and hide the "Other" series when the user hides "Total" using the legend?

Would be fine (as plan B) to use the button function, but can't make sense of the implementation of that button in this case. Extra points for making it work without using the button!

I appreciate the help!

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    type: 'area'
},
title: {
    text: 'Latte Purchases'
},
subtitle: {
    text: 'At The Coffee House'
},
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul'],
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
    title: {
        enabled: false
    }
},
yAxis: {
    labels: {
        formatter: function () {
            return this.value / 1;
        }
    }
},
tooltip: {
    split: true,
    valueSuffix: ' visits'
},
plotOptions: {
    area: {
        stacking: 'normal',
        lineColor: '#666666',
        lineWidth: 1,
        marker: {
            lineWidth: 1,
            lineColor: '#ffffff'
        }
    }
},
series: [{
    name: 'All',
    stack: null,
    color: '#616161',
    fillColor: '#616161',
    data: [44, 50, 63, 78, 82, 86, 100]
}, {
    name: 'Latte',
    color: '#26c4ee',
    stack: true,
    data: [19, 22, 24, 24, 28, 32, 34],
    marker: {
        fillColor: '#26c4ee'
    }
}, {
    name: 'Other',
    fillColor: '#616161',
    showInLegend: false,
    showPoint: false,
    linkedTo: 'Total',
    stack: true,
    data: [25, 28, 39, 54, 54, 54, 66],
    marker: {
            enabled: false,
            states: {
                hover: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        }
}]
```

});

Comment: Set linkedTo option to the correct id of the series - https://jsfiddle.net/wcvsco0o/10/ I am not sure if it is what you want, though. Better explanation might help.

Comment: This did it... Thank you! And no fair... I have that code in the above, but it wasn't working until you did it. ;^) (at least, I don't see a major difference)